# "Art was theatre was sport"

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

I seem to have come across this sentence structure before but I can't quite remember where. Which number would be the best follow up to the phrase "To the ancient Romans"?

To the ancient Romans

1. theatre was art was sport
2. theatre was art, was sport.
3. theatre was art and art was sport.

I know that 3. is correct. 2. is basically the same as 1. but with an added comma. However, the message I'd like to convey is that art = theatre = sport (i.e. sport was art because it was theatre and theatre was art) rather than that sport is intrinsically art. Sport is only art because it is theatre.

Sorry if the question is longwinded and confusing. Thank you so much for taking the time to read and answer this everyone.

Comment: 1 & 2 are "ungrammatical" colloquialisms, only appropriate in certain "relaxed" written contexts.

Comment: In what context are you writing? I like the way "To the ancient Romans, theater was art, was sport," rolls off the tongue. It makes sense. However it seems to me that you've changed the meaning with the order you've chosen for the words. Wouldn't it be: "To the ancient Romans, sport was theater and theater was art."

Answer (score 1):

The most famous instance in the English language of daisy-chained verbs and nouns of the general type that the poster asks about is surely Gertrude Stein's line in her poem "Sacred Emily" (1913):

> Rose is a rose is a rose is a rose.

although it remains a mystery to me why this line gained mainstream recognition as something approaching a commonplace, while the beautiful and evocative earlier line

> Push sea push sea push sea push sea push sea push sea push sea push sea.

has never really emerged from obscurity. Anyway, I checked for earlier (specifically, nineteenth-century) instances of this type of construction (preferably in contexts where artfulness didn't render literal meaning almost entirely opaque), and found several interesting examples.

Rev. William Tooke (translator), "[What renders the Observance of the divine Commandments easy](http://books.google.com/books?id=GIoAAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA108&dq=%22is+life+is%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9TkqU6iLJ8vuoAS3_ILoDw&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=%22is%20life%20is%22&f=false)," in *Sermons on Education, on Reflection, on the Greaatness of God in the Works of Nature ... From the German of the Rev. George Joachim Zollikofer* (1806):

> Yes, to thee all is in subjection ; at thy nod worlds arise and pass away ; thee both heaven and earth obey, the whole innumerable host of suns and stars, and the sand on the shores of the ocean, the most exalted spirit that worships before thy throne, and the worm that crawls in the dust ; **and to obey thee is truth, is order, is life, is felicity**. Yes, all thy laws are perfect wisdom and benignity, pure sources and methods of content and satisfaction.

From "[A Chapter on Credit](http://books.google.com/books?id=2y4ZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA417&dq=%22is+life+is%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=njkqU8fMCInfoATx5oGAAw&ved=0CF0Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22is%20life%20is%22&f=false)," in *The Plaindealer*, volume 1 (June 3, 1837):

> Credit is a new mechanical power, which Great Britain devised in part, which the United States was perfecting, but which the rough fingers of rude experimenters have destroyed for the present. **Credit is life, is food — ay, the very air in which a republic breathes**.

(Note that the author in this case omitted the expected *is* between "ay," and "the very air.")

Rev. H. Ballou, "[The Path of Life](http://books.google.com/books?id=_CsrAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA145&dq=%22is+life+is%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=njkqU8fMCInfoATx5oGAAw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22is%20life%20is%22&f=false)," in *The Universalist and Ladies' Repository*, volume 6 (September 1837):

> The general subject of the foregoing remarks bas not been correctly understood and explained by our christian divines, in times past. They have not been in the habit of teaching the people, that **obedience to the divine commands is life, is fullness of joy, and is pleasures forevermore**.

"[Celebration at Zanesville](http://books.google.com/books?id=pNwqAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA314&dq=%22was+truth+was%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hzoqU_uZA8HwoATao4KgDg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22was%20truth%20was%22&f=false)," from the *Columbus [Ohiio] Statesman*, quoted in *Freemason's Monthly Magazine*, volume 2 (August 1, 1843):

> Infidelity to God, he [the Rev. John Newland Maffit] said, formed a barrier to man's becoming a Mason ; and stated that it was based upon religion — that **Masonry was truth, was love, was charity**. History was deeply indebted to it for much that would otherwise have been lost, but which had been preserved in the archives of the lodge.

In all of these instances, the authors seem to have viewed the sprigs of language beginning with the repeated verb as parallel branches off the base noun to which they attached; and the authors indicated the parallel status of these sprigs by using commas to separate them. Applying that treatment to the poster's example, we get this:

> To the ancient Romans, theatre was art, was sport.

That method of punctuating the sentence (which is almost identical to the poster's option #2) seems perfectly reasonable, although writers usually adopt less poetical constructions. For example,

> To the ancient Romans, theatre was both art and sport.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It's been incredibly well thought out.